# How to get re-rendered version of Server Component Page when navigated to using client side navigation in NextJs 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the below NextJs page which is a Server Component. Since it has dynamic data fetching with `cache: 'no-store'`, data is fetched and page gets newly rendered on the server every time the page is reloaded on the browser. But if the page is navigated to by a Link, the last rendered version sent from the server is shown on the ui. Is it possible to trigger data fetching on the server and fetch a new rendered version from the server even when the page is navigated to by a Link?

```
const getUser = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/', { cache: 'no-store' });
  const responseData = await response.json()
  return responseData.results[0]
}

export default async function User() {
  const { name: {title, first,last} } = await getUser()
  return (
    <div>{`${title} ${first} ${last}`}</div>
  )
}
```